# Get error messages when creating a new function

Tags: c

I have a homework assignment where I had to modify the code and add an additional option to divide an integer by two. However, when I added my section I keep getting an error message.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()

{

/* variable definition: */ 

int intValue, menuSelect,Results;
float floatValue;

intValue = 1; 

// While a positive number

while (intValue > 0)

{   

 printf ("Enter a positive Integer\n: ");

 scanf("%d", &intValue);

 if (intValue > 0)

{

 printf ("Enter 1 to calculate Square, 2 to Calculate Cube, 3 to divide by 2 \n: ");

 scanf("%d", &menuSelect);

 if (menuSelect == 1)

 {

   // Call the Square Function

   Results = Square(intValue);

   printf("Square of %d is %d\n",intValue,Results);

 }

 else if (menuSelect == 2)

 {

   // Call the Cube function

   Results = Cube(intValue);

   printf("Cube of %d is %d\n",intValue,Results);

 }

 else if (menuSelect == 3)

 {

    //Call the half function

    Results = divide2(floatValue);

    printf("Half of %d is %f\n", intValue,Results);

 }

 else 

   printf("Invalid menu item, only 1 or 2 is accepted\n");

 }     

 }     

return 0;

}

/* function returning the Square of a number */

int Square(int value)

{

return value*value;

} 

/* function returning the Cube of a number */

int Cube(int value)

{
return value*value*value;

}

//Function returning the half of a number

float divide2(float value)

{
return value/2;

}
```

And the errors I'm getting are:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:38:18: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Square'       [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    Results = Square(intValue);
              ^
prog.c:50:18: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Cube' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    Results = Cube(intValue);
              ^
prog.c:62:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'divide2' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   Results = divide2(floatValue);
             ^
prog.c:64:14: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
   printf("Half of %d is %f\n", intValue,Results);
          ^
prog.c: At top level:
prog.c:101:7: error: conflicting types for 'divide2'
float divide2(float value)
   ^
prog.c:62:17: note: previous implicit declaration of 'divide2' was here
   Results = divide2(floatValue);
             ^
```

What is wrong with the code? I didn't get the messages when running the original code

Comment: When writing C code, imagine you are telling the compiler to understand your code one piece at a time. You need to introduce functions that other parts of the code uses before that usage occurs. In your specific example, `main` is before `Square`, so the compiler does not really know what to do when it first sees your `Square` call. Try ordering your functions according to this principle and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Just use prototypes for all functions before the `main` function and then define them afterwards.

Comment: Add prototypes or define the function before actually calling them  i.e. If you are calling from main(), define them before main().

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a prototype of a function if you are defining it after the point where you have called it

Example:

```
ABC();

void ABC(){
//do some stuff
}
```

Will not work unless we add `void ABC();` before calling ABC();

This will also work fine:

```
void ABC(){
//do something
}

ABC();
```

Comment: I was able to get the code to work by introducing the functions before the main. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `ABC();` is illegal, a prototype would be `int ABC(void);` or `void ABC(void);`

Comment: It is not illegal it will just not check if any value is provided for the function.

Answer (score 1):

You should use prototypes just below the includes:

```
int Square(int value);
int Cube(int value);
float Divide2(float value);
```

If you don't want use prototypes. a option is put all the methods up the main function, this isn't recommendable but it works.

The prototypes are references to the compiler and they tell beforehand to functions as they should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that works (I changed some variable names because you can't use `results` for both int and float and I also changed the loop to check if the number is greater than *OR* equal to 0, since 0 is considered positive and square/cube/half are well-defined for 0). I will make one function defined at the top; since they are small, they are easy to one-line, and generally for one-liners I define them right at the top, but the rest I will just prototype at the top and later define (just so you can see both styles).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int square(int value);
int cube(int value);
/* Function returning the half of a number */
float divide2(float value) { return value / 2; }

int main()
{
    int number, menu_select, int_result;
    float float_result;

    number = 1;

    // While a positive number
    while (number >= 0)
    {
            printf("Enter a positive Integer\n: ");
            scanf("%d", &number);

            if (number > 0)
            {
                    printf("Enter 1 to calculate Square, 2 to Calculate Cube, 3 to divide by 2\n: ");
                    scanf("%d", &menu_select);

                    switch (menu_select)
                    {
                    case 1:
                            // Call the square Function
                            int_result = square(number);
                            printf("Square of %d is %d\n", number, int_result);
                            break;
                    case 2:
                            // Call the cube function
                            int_result = cube(number);
                            printf("cube of %d is %d\n", number, int_result);
                            break;
                    case 3:
                            // Call the half function
                            float_result = divide2(number);
                            printf("Half of %d is %f\n", number, float_result);
                            break;
                    default:
                            printf("Invalid menu item, only 1 or 2 is accepted\n");
                    }
            }
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Function returning the square of a number */
int square(int value)
{
    return value * value;
}

/* Function returning the cube of a number */
int cube(int value)
{
    return value * value * value;
}
```

I also changed your series of `if`/`else`'s to a single `switch` to make the code neater and so you can see the power of `switch`. Although I have never personally used them, these functions seem ideal candidates for `inline`ing.

You might also want to specify a field with for your `printf` for your float value, so it could look like `0.50` e.g. instead of `0.500000`. Here is how you would specify two digits after the decimal point:

```
printf("Here is a float value: %.2f\n", float_var);
```

Just change the "2" in `%.2f` to whatever you like if you'd like to specify the precision.